# Impact of DC in Cassandra Cluster for Consistency ONE

Tags: cassandra, nosql, datastax, eventual-consistency

I am learning Cassandra architecture & have set-up a Cassandra cluster in virtual machine like below:

```
Node_1 -> DC_1 -> Rack1 -> rf = 1
Node_2 and Node_3 -> DC_2 -> Rack1 -> rf = 1
```

For Consistency Level ONE :

1. When Node_1 and Node_3 are down, select query fails on Node_2 (***Warning from Cassandra console*** : Consistency One cannot be set; ***Error from cqlsh*** : NoHostAvailable)
2. When Node_1 and Node_2 are down, select query fails on Node_3 (***Warning from Cassandra console*** : Consistency One cannot be set; ***Error from cqlsh*** : NoHostAvailable)
3. But When Node_2 and Node_3 are down, then select query **passes** on Node_1(***Warning from Cassandra console*** : Consistency One cannot be set; ***Error from cqlsh* : No Error, displays the table data**)

Noticed same behaviour for write as well.

Does this behaviour have something to do with nodes being in same or different DCs? Please explain the reason for this mismatch.

Comment: What is the replication factor for your keyspaces?

Comment: keyspace has rf=1 for dc1 and rf=1 for dc2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NoHostAvailable`  comes up when replicas with the data are not up and cluster cannot respond the requested data. In your case you are writing one replica on each Datacenter (DC_1 and DC_2). So it might have happened that when you shut down following combo `Node_1 (DC_1) and Node_2(DC_2) nodes` or `Node_1 (DC_1) and Node_3(DC_2) nodes`, you are not getting all the requested data from the live nodes.
In case of Node_1 up you are sure that all your data will be retrieved since DC_1 contains 1 replica of data always and Node_1 is the only node in this datacenter. Hence you get the requested data.

Answer (score 1):

I was doing `select *` query always which failed for node 2/3 when node 1,3/2 was down which as Manish rightly pointed out in accepted answer fails because node 1 will always have entire data while node 2 and 3 have partial data.

But when I did `select * from <table> where partition_key=<key on node 2>`, (other 2 nodes are down) it gave me result with consistency one as this time node2 owned the requested partition.